# replace css class when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to replace
div class="rich fomat2 type-a"     with
div class=“standard format1 type-a”

But I can only change the html when it loads because I'm using a website creating software that automatically outputs html. So I used function onload().

I tried .attr() as well as .getElementsByClassName() but neither worked.
Where am I going wrong? Any help?

```
    function onload() {$('div') .attr('rich format2 type-a', ' standard format1 type-a') ; } window.onload =onload; }            
window.onload = onload;

    function onload(){
var els = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("rich format2 type-a"));
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *\brich format2 type-a\b/g, "standard format1 type-a");
} window.onload = onload;
```

Comment: You can't have spaces in attribute names.

Comment: `.attr()` is a jQuery function, and if you want to change classes, `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` are probably better suited if you're already using jQuery.

Comment: @Andreas
I have also tried .removeClass() and .addClass(). But that did not work as well.
Here is what I did.
        function onload() { $(.removeClass(' rich format2 type-a').addClass(' standard format1 type-1'); } window.onload = onload;

Comment: @adeneo

   
 
Well I'm using a Website creating software which automatically outputs an html. So I can only change it when it loads. The html it spells out is as follows. <div id="block1" class="block framed"> <div class="col-1"> <div class="rich fomat2 type-a"> I want to change div class “rich format2 type-a” to “standard format1 type-a” The original class has comes with spaces from the beginning. It is default.

Answer (score 1):

you would have a div with a class

```
<div class="abc"></div>
```

In jQuery, you might do the following

```
$('.abc').removeClass('abc').addClass('newClass');
```

Lets say your div looks like this

```
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

This actually means, that you div contains 3 diferent classes. And, therefor have to be called that way.

```
$('.a.b.c').removeClass('a').removeClass('b').removeClass('c').addClass('newClass');
```

Hope it helps.
Jonas

Comment: You can remove multiple classes in one statement: `removeClass('a b c')`.

Comment: I am aware of that. This was simply to illustrate the point, that spaces in a class="" parameter equals 3 different classes, not one.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

This function is used to get/set an attribute.

The first field is the name of the attribute, the *optional* second is the new value.

```
$("div").attr("class", "def");
```

Note that the name of the attribute is class, so the first field's value is "class".

Since you want to select only divs that have the class `.abc`, put that in the selector:

```
$("div.abc").attr("class", "def");
```

---

### 2. Class Syntax

The other major error that is present in your code, pointed out by [**@adeneo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo), is that classes cannot have spaces in them.

`class="a b c"` implies "Use classes `.a, .b, and .c`"

Because of this, `.getElementsByClassName()` is failing.

If this is intended, you can use a combined class selector:

```
$("div.a.b.c").attr("class", "def");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery toggleClass - https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("div")
      .toggleClass('a b c');
      .toggleClass('d e f');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here is my solution. Appreciate your time.

```
$('div').removeClass('a b c').addClass('d e f');
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/4WAWZ/)**